# If $T_t$ is the flow generated by the autonomous velocity $v$ and $\left.v\right|_{\partial\Omega}=0$, then $T_t(\partial\Omega)=\partial\Omega$

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry, numerical-methods, differential-topology, diffeomorphism

Let $d\in\mathbb N$ and $v\in C_c^\infty(\mathbb R^d,\mathbb R^d)$. We know that, for any $\tau>0$, there is a unique solution $X^x\in C^0([0,\tau],\mathbb R^d)$ of \begin{align}X'(t)&=v(X(t))\tag1&\text{for all }t\in[0,\tau],\\X(0)&=x\end{align} for all $x\in\mathbb R^d$. It is easy to show that $$T_t(x):=X^x(t)\;\;\;\text{for }t\in[0,\tau]$$ is a $C^1$-diffeomorphism from $\mathbb R^d$ onto $\mathbb R^d$.

> Now let $\Omega\subseteq\mathbb R^d$. How can we show that,
>
> 1. if $\left.v\right|_{\partial\Omega}=0$, then $$T_t(\partial\Omega)=\partial\Omega\tag2$$ for all $t\in[0,\tau]$?
> 2. if $\Omega$ is closed or open, then $$T_t(\Omega)=\Omega\tag3$$ for all $t\in[0,\tau]$?

[It's clear to me](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3787698/47771) that any homeomorphism maps boundary (interior) points to boundary (interior) points. I guess we need to use this somehow.

**EDIT**: From the comments it is clear that $(2)$ holds, since it should generally hold that if $B$ is any subset of $\mathbb R^d$ with $\left.v\right|_B=0$, then $T_t(x)=x$ for all $x\in B$. But how can we prove $(3)$?

**EDIT 2**: If $f$ is any homeomorphism between topological spaces $E_1$ and $E_2$ and $B_1\subseteq E_1$, then we know that $f(B_1^\circ)=f(B_1)^\circ$, $f(\partial B_1)=\partial f(B_1)$ and $f(\overline{B_1})=\overline{f(B_1)}$. If $B_1$ os open, then $B_1=B_1^\circ$ and if $B_1$ is closed, then $B_1=\overline{B_1}$. I think we need to use this for $(3)$.

**EDIT 3**: Let $x\in\Omega^\circ$. Then there is a $\varepsilon>0$ with $B_\varepsilon(x)\subseteq\Omega$. Maybe we can at least show that there is a $t\in[0,\tau]$ (sufficiently small) such that $\left\|X^x(s)-x\right\|<\varepsilon$ for all $s\in[0,t]$. Then it would follow that $$T_s(\Omega^\circ)\subseteq\Omega^\circ\;\;\;\text{for all }s\in[0,t].\tag4$$ From pure intuition, for a sufficiently small $t$, the velocity should not be able to move the point $x$ outside of the ball $B_\varepsilon(x)$. So, $(4)$ should hold. (How would we need to argue that it must even be an equality? This seems trivial, by bijectivity though.)

Comment: For $(2)$, there's a simpler argument: the flow map $T_t(x)$ satisfies $\frac{d}{dt}T_t(x)=0$ for $x\in\partial M$. The only solution to this ODE is the constant function.

Comment: Indeed, as @Kajelad points out, the boundary not only maps to itself, but it stays pointwise fixed. If $v$ was everywhere *tangent* to $\partial\Omega$, then the flow would preserve the boundary, but individual points would move around.

Comment: @Kajelad What exactly did you use? It's clear to me that $\frac\partial{{\rm d}t}T_t(x)=v(t,T_t(x))$ (assuming, more generally, that $v$ depends on $t$ as well). It seems like you've used that $T_t(x)\in\partial\Omega$ if $x\in\partial\Omega$? But how do we know that? The only thing that I know is that $\partial T_t(\Omega)=T_t(\partial\Omega)$.

Comment: @TedShifrin Please take note of my comment above. I'd also be interested in whether we can generalize this to *any* subset which is invariant under homeomorphisms (is there a characterization of those sets?).

Comment: It follows from the fact that for the ODE $\frac{d}{dt}x(t)=v(x(t),t)$ with initial condition $x(0)=x_0$, if $v(x_0,t)=0$, then $x(t)=x_0$ (provided $v$ is locally Lipschitz).

Comment: @Kajelad I'm not able to prove your claim literally, but maybe you mean the following: If $t\in[0,t]$ and $v(s,X(0)=0$ for all $s\in[0,t]$, then $\left\|v(s,X(s))\right\|\le c\left\|X(s)-X(0)\right\|$, where $c$ is constant of Lipschitz continuity of $v$ (I'm assuming $v$ is Lipschitz in the second argument uniformly wrt the first) and hence $\sup_{s\le t}\left\|X(s)-X(0)\right\|\le c\int_0^t\sup_{r\le s}\left\|X(r)-X(0)\right\|{\rm d}s$. This implies $\sup_{s\le t}\left\|X(s)-X(0)\right\|=0$ by Gronwall's inequality. Is that what you meant?

Comment: @Kajelad You wrote that $v(t,X(0)=0$ implies $X(t)=X(0)$ ($t$ is fixed), but I don't think that's correct.

Comment: What I mean is that $v(t,x(0))=0\ \forall t\in I\implies x(t)=x(0)\ \forall t\in I$, where $I$ is an interval containing $0$. It follows from Picard-Lindelöf theorem, provided $v$ is Lipschitz (in this case it is smooth).

Comment: @Kajelad How is this different from what I wrote? You don't need Picard-Lindelöf (I guess you've got especially the uniqueness result in mind) at this point. As I've shown above, we obtain $\sup_{s\le t}\left\|X(s)-X(0)\right\|=0$ from Gronwall's inequality. And this is clearly equivalent to $X(s)=X(0)$ for all $s\in[0,t]$.

Comment: @TedShifrin Just to be sure, this has nothing to do with the boundary, right? It should generally hold that if $B$ is any subset with $\left.v\right|_B=0$, then $T_t(x)=x$ for all $x\in B$. Or am I missing something?

Comment: My previous comment was merely clarifying what I meant in the one before that; your argument seems to work as well.

Comment: Are you asking how to prove (3)?

Comment: And what is the assumption on $\Omega$?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: @ArcticChar Yes, sorry. Confused the numbering of bullet points and equations. The assumption is that $\Omega$ is either closed or open.

Comment: Do we still have the assumption $v|_{\partial \Omega} = 0$?

Comment: @ArcticChar Yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

About the second question, you can go like this.
This is a formal argument for the more intuitive "you can't cross the boundary if the boundary is fixed, so you gotta stay inside".

Firstly, suppose that $\Omega$ is open. Take $x \in \Omega$. The map

$$ T_{()}(x): [0, \tau] \to \mathbb{R}^d $$

that sends $t$ to $T_t(x) $  is continous, thus the preimage of $\Omega$ is open. We then get that

$$A(x) =  \{t \in [0, \tau] : T_t(x) \in \Omega\} $$

is open. Suppose by contradiction that there exist $x$ such that $A(x)$ is not $[0,\tau]$. Take $t(x) = \sup \{ t: \forall s \in [0, t] , T_s(x) \in \Omega\}$.Set $y=T_{t_*(x) }(x) $.

Notice that:

1. $y \not \in \Omega$. Indeed, $t_*(x) < \tau$ because otherwise we would have $A(x) = [0,\tau]$. If $T_{t_*(x) }(x) $ was in $\Omega$, then by openness of $A(x) $ we'd have that $T_{t_*(x) +\epsilon}(x) $ would be in $\Omega$ for all sufficiently small $\epsilon$, contradicting the sup hypothesis.
2. $y \in \partial \Omega$. Indeed, we have that

$$ T_{t_*(x) }(x) = \lim_{t\to t_*(x)-} T_t(x) $$

And all the points in the limit belong to $\Omega$. Using also point 1 we get that $T_{t_*(x) }(x) \in \bar{\Omega} \setminus \Omega = \partial \Omega$.

This concludes, because $T_{t_*(x) }$ would not be injective: both $x, y$ are mapped to $y$.

The same argument applies also to negative times, yielding the equality $T_t(\Omega) = \Omega$. Indeed, take $z \in \Omega$: then $T_t (T_{-t}(z)) = z$, and $T_{-t}(z) \in \Omega$.

Finally, if we take $\Omega$ to be closed, by the previous points we get $T_t(\Omega^c) = \Omega^c$; being bijective, this yield $T_t(\Omega) = \Omega$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. As I read your answer, I've started to wonder whether we could prove the claim by considering (for a fixed $x\in\Omega$ and $X:=X^x$) $I:=X^{-1}(\Omega)$ (which is, as you said, $[0,\tau]$-open) and $\sigma:=\inf([0,\tau]\setminus I)$, instead. So, I've tried to prove $\sigma\not\in I$. And, as you did, assuming the contrary, i.e. $\sigma\in I$, would yield that there is a $\varepsilon>0$ with $B_\varepsilon(\sigma)\cap[0,\tau]\subseteq I$ and hence $[0,\tau]\setminus I\subseteq[0,\tau]\setminus B_\varepsilon(\sigma)$.

Comment: But I don't see why this is a contradiction if $\sigma=0$. Then I looked at your proof and realized that your proof of $y\in\partial\Omega$ won't work if your $t_\ast(x)=0$. So, why can we exclude this possibility? And can we fix my prove attempt?

Comment: I'll get to your attempt later. Meanwhile, notice that $t_*(x) $ can't be zero, because our $x$ starts in $\Omega$! Hope this helps you to fix your attempt :)

Comment: I've already accepted your answer and awarded the bounty, but please take a look at [my answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3806185/47771). What do you think? And it's still not clear to me why $(11)$ is an equality; in the same way, it is not clear to me how you solved the problem by considering "negative times". Is this really necessary?

Comment: I think your reasoning with the "negative times" is that in the case where $v$ does not depend on time (as in the question) the inverse of $T_t$ is equal to $T_{-1}$ or, alternative, to the family corresponding to the solution for $-v$. But what can we do when $v$ does depend on time? (Please take note of my related question: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3842350/47771)

Comment: In order to show $T_t(\Omega)\subseteq\Omega$ for all $t$, we only need to assume $\operatorname{Bd}\Omega\subseteq T_t(\operatorname{Bd}\Omega)$ for all $t$. But how do you obtain the equality $T_t(\Omega)=\Omega$ for all $t$? Your idea seems to be to apply the same reasoning to $v$ replaced by $-v$ and using that $T_t^{-1}=T_t^{(-v)}$ for all $t$, where $(T_t^{(-v)})_t$ denotes the family corresponding to the solution of $(1)$ for $v$ replaced by $-v$. However, how do you know that it still holds $\operatorname{Bd}\Omega\subseteq T_t^{(-v)}(\operatorname{Bd}\Omega)$ for all $t$?

Answer (score 1):

[Andrea Marino's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3805092/47771) is perfectly fine, I'm mainly writing down a similar attempt for my own reference.

First of all, [we can show](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3805526/47771) the following result:

> Let $\tau>0$, $s\in[0,\tau]$, $E$ be a $\mathbb R$-Banach space and $f\in C^0([s,\tau],E)$.
>
> **Proposition 1**: Let $B\subseteq E$ be closed and $$I:=f^{-1}(B)=\{t\in[s,\tau]:f(t)\in B\}.$$ If $I\ne\emptyset$, then
>
> 1. $\sigma:=\inf I\in I$ and hence $f(\sigma)\in B$;
> 2. if $f(0)\not\in B$, then $\sigma>s$ and $f(sigma)\in\partial B$.
>
> **Corollary 2**: Let $\Omega\subseteq E$ be open and $$I:=\{t\in[s,\tau]:f(t)\not\in\Omega\}.$$ If $I\ne\emptyset$, then
>
> 1. $\sigma:=\in I\in I$ and hence $f(\sigma)\not\in\Omega$;
> 2. if $f(0)\in\Omega$, then $\sigma>s$ and $f(\sigma)\in\partial\Omega$.

Now, turning to the question, assume $v:[0,\tau]\times E\to E$ is uniformly Lipschitz continuous in the second argument uniformly with respect to the second and $v(\;\cdot\;,x)\in C^0([0,\tau],E)$ for all $x\in E$. Then there is a unique $X^{s,\:x}\in C^0([s,\tau],E)$ with $$X^{s,\:x}(t)=x+\int_s^tv(r,X^{s,\:x}(r))\:{\rm d}r\;\;\;\text{for all }t\in[s,\tau]\tag1$$ for all $(s,x)\in[0,\tau]\times E$. We can show that $$T_{s,\:t}(x)=X^{s,\:x}(t)\;\;\;\text{for }x\in E$$ is bijective for all $0\le s\le t\le\tau$.

> **Proposition 3**: Let $(s,x)\in[0,\tau]\times E$. If $$v(t,x)=0\;\;\;\text{for all }t\in[s,\tau],\tag2$$ then $$X^{s,\:x}=x\tag3.$$

(This can be proven using the Lipschitz assumption and Gronwall's inequality.)

> **Corollary 4**: Let $(s,x)\in[0,\tau]\times E$ and $\Omega\subseteq E$ be open or closed. If $$v(t,x)=0\;\;\;\text{for all }(t,x)\in[s,\tau]\times\partial\Omega\tag4,$$ then $$T_{s,\:t}(\Omega)=\Omega\;\;\;\text{for all }t\in[s,\tau].\tag5$$

*Proof*: We first show the following: Let $x\in\Omega$. If $\Omega$ is open, then $$T_{s,\:t}(x)\in\Omega\;\;\;\text{for all }t\in[s,\tau]\tag6.$$ In order to prove that, let $$I:=\{t\in[s,\tau]:X^{s,\:x}(t)\not\in\Omega\}.$$ Assume the claim is not true, i.e. $I\ne\emptyset$. Then, by Corollary 2, $$\sigma:=\inf I\in I\tag7$$ and $$y:=X^{s,\:x}(\sigma)\in\partial\Omega.$$ Thus, by $(2)$, $$v(t,y)=0\;\;\;\text{for all }t\in[s,\tau]\tag8$$ and hence $$T_{s,\:t}(y)=y\;\;\;\text{for all }t\in[s,\tau]\tag9$$ by Proposition 3. On the other hand, by definition, $$T_{s,\:\sigma}(x)=y\tag{10}.$$ Since $\Omega$ is open, $\Omega\cap\partial\Omega=\emptyset$ and hence $x\ne y$. But by $(9)$ and $(10)$ this implies that $T_{s,\:\sigma}$ is not injective; which is not true. So, $I=\emptyset$.

> However, what we can infer from this claim is $$T_{s,\:t}(\Omega)\subseteq\Omega\;\;\;\text{for all }t\in[s,\tau],\tag{11}$$ **but why is $(11)$ actually an equality**?

**EDIT**: Couldn't we simply apply the same prove to $[s,\tau]\ni t\mapsto T_{s,\:t}^{-1}(x)$, where $x\in\Omega$ is fixed as in the first claim of my proof above? If I'm not missing something, the only relevant part was the continuity of $[s,\tau]\ni t\mapsto T_{s,\:t}(x)$ and we can show that $[s,\tau]\ni t\mapsto T_{s,\:t}^{-1}(x)$ is continuous as well. So, the proof of that claim should follow line-by-line yielding $T_{s,\:t}^{-1}(x)\in\Omega$ for all $t\in[s,\tau]$. What do you think?