Proof that a homeomorphism map boundaries to boundaries
I want to prove that if I have two topological spaces $X$ and $Y$, with $A \subset X$, and a homeomorphism $f : X \to Y$, then $f(\partial A) = \partial \big(f(A)\big)$.
I saw a proof here: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3502105/1053101 (the point (2)). But I don't understand. I mean.. why we can find $a, b \in X$ with $a \in A \cap f^{-1}(V)$ and $b \in A^c \cap f^{-1}(V)$ ? And why is $a,b \ne x$ if $f$ is bijective?
Or, if you could help me with another proof it will be nice. I searched in textbooks but I didn't find something useful. Thanks!

But from where results that $A$ is closed?

And I still don't understand if it is possible to find $a,b \in X$. I think at $X = {1,2}$ with topology $\tau = {\emptyset, {1}, {2}, {1, 2}}$. How can I find 2 elements different from $x$?

@Masacroso thanks! I think I understand now! So a one more question regarding my initial proof. So that is wrong, correct?
